# Deploying Flask app on Heroku giving build error

Tags: python, heroku, flask, deployment, build-error

I have come up with a flask app in python which is running fine on localhost server.

Now while deploying it on the cloud service Heroku, the build is failing with the following error:

```
remote:          Downloading distribute-0.6.24.tar.gz (620kB)
remote:            Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
remote:            Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:              File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
remote:              File "/tmp/pip-install-_ofp1xky/distribute/setuptools/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
remote:                from setuptools.extension import Extension, Library
remote:              File "/tmp/pip-install-_ofp1xky/distribute/setuptools/extension.py", line 2, in <module>
remote:                from setuptools.dist import _get_unpatched
remote:              File "/tmp/pip-install-_ofp1xky/distribute/setuptools/dist.py", line 103
remote:                except ValueError, e:
remote:                                 ^
remote:            SyntaxError: invalid syntax
remote:            
remote:            ----------------------------------------
remote:        Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-_ofp1xky/distribute/
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
```

Below is my requirements.txt ::

```
docutils==0.11

MarkupSafe==0.19
Pygments==1.6
Sphinx==1.2.2

requests==1.2.0
Flask==0.10.1
Jinja2==2.6
Werkzeug==0.8.3
certifi==0.0.8
chardet==1.0.1
distribute==0.6.24
gunicorn==0.14.2
```

Please help! Thanks Newbie to Flask.

Comment: Which version of python you use ?

Comment: i am using python 2.7

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you should update the `distribute` requirement to the with the release of `distribute-0.7.3`. Keep in mind also that heroku supports latest python but you can change the runtime if you want to support  https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes

Apart from that you can completely remove the `distribute` as it is not needed and it's just an example in heroku. Flask app can run without this.

Also better to use the recommend style with `Pipfile` instead of requirements.

A nice example of flask for heroku if you want to check https://github.com/yefim/flask-heroku-sample